# Hide the Wolfram Cloud Activity window

Tags: wolfram-cloud, dialog-window

I'm new to Mathematica. I use Wolfram Cloud to save my notebooks and I've enabled autosave. So, whenever I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (after saving once), the notebook gets saved on the cloud. The problem is that every time it saves, I get an annoying window of Wolfram Cloud Activity which pops up and takes up my screen space. How do I disable the showing of the Activity window or at least make the window not appear in the foreground? I'm using Mathematica 12.0.0.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: FYI: I failed to find tracks of this prompt in `NotebookEventActions` so I don't know how to intercept it. I tried to move the original dialog to `$UserBaseDirectory` but it was ignored. Then I tried to modify the original one in `$InstallationDirectory` (make it Visible->Flase for example) but somehow it still was visible each other time I saved the notebook. That was the point when I gave up :)